# Can IntelliJ disassemble the java byte code of a third party (or JDK) without the respective source code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, disassembly

I am looking for something similar to what the Reflector VS plugin does for .NET

Answer (score 2):

**IntelliJ IDEA 14** comes with a built-in Java decompiler:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/07/intellij-idea-14-eap-138-1029-is-out/

Now you can download a preview version from their official website.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick google I found

http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdintellij

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ideajad/

http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=126

http://code.google.com/p/intellijad/

Answer (score 0):

I know Netbeans does something like this - just click on a `.class` file of a dependency and it'll do it automatically. It doesn't produce Java Source, but the comments give a pretty good idea of what is going on for simple operations.